# complex nested data representation

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get all `Currency` objects with the `Ticker` objects nested in each currency object. So far i've only been able to get the tickers with the currency object inside, but this is really not convenient? i'm not sure what changes i need to make to achieve below output

so for instance what i want is something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Dollar",
        "symbol": "USD"
        "ticker": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "rank": 1,
                "price_dkk": 123.25
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**models**

```
class Currency(models.Model):
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=4, default='BTC', unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Bitcoin', unique=True)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'static/img/currencies', blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = _('currencies')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Ticker(models.Model):
    currency = models.ForeignKey('Currency', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rank = models.IntegerField()
    price_dkk = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=6)
    market_cap_dkk = models.BigIntegerField()
    percent_change_1h = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    percent_change_24h = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    percent_change_7d = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = _('Ticker')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

**serializer**

```
class CurrencyTickerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    currency = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False, queryset=Currency.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Ticker
        fields = ('currency', 'rank', 'price_dkk', 'market_cap_dkk', 'percent_change_1h', 'percent_change_24h', 'percent_change_7d',)
```

**View**

```
class CurrencyTickerGetView(ProtectedResourceView):
    def get(self, request):
        tickers = CurrencyTickerSerializer(Ticker.objects.all(), many=True)

        return JsonResponse(tickers.data, safe=False)
```

Comment: What do you get so far? Do you have any error?

Comment: so far as you can see in the newly added `View` i just get the tickers, since i'm not really have added currency to serializer or view, but i'm not really sure where to start in order to get the data i need, i'm open to sugestion on changing models etc.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use nested relationships. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships.

You will need two serializers. One for you currency model, and one for your tickers..

In your currency serializer you will need to reference your tickets serializer.

```
class CurrencySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     tickers = CurrencyTickerModelSerializer(many=True)
     ...
```

In your view grab all the currencies you want to serialize and make sure you prefetch_related the tickers that you will be serializing ahead of time or you could end up with a  lot of queries.